# Download file with phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner plugin using Phonegap/Cordova IONIC

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing an app, I use [phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner) plugin to scan QR Code, and it works fine.

I want to do two following things:

1. Detect if the code scanned is a link or file (example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/weutq8nt88saryx/MyFileDropbox.pdf?dl=0)
2. Download this file automatically.

Or:

1. Open that link in a browser.

For now I have this code.

```
app.controller('BarCodeController', function($scope , $cordovaBarcodeScanner){
$scope.scanBarcode= function(){
console.log("CLICK");
alert("click");

$cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(function(barcodeData){
  alert(barcodeData.text);
  console.log("formato "+barcodeData.format);
},function(error){
  console.log("Error: "+error);
});
}
});
```

Please guide me

Comment: What have you tried so far in attempting to implement the items in your 'I want to do two things' list? If you can show that code and what you have tried so far, then it might be easier for others to offer help.

Comment: If you change `https://www.dropbox.com/s/weutq8nt88saryx/MyFileDropbox.pdf?dl=0` to `https://www.dropbox.com/s/weutq8nt88saryx/MyFileDropbox.pdf?dl=1` it will start autodownload in case of DB.

Comment: I'm new with this framework, and I don't know what to do. Please help me

Comment: You can use https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer to download a file and [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) or https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser to open the link in external browser or inside your app correspondingly.

Comment: thanks! I will try